# Undefined Control Sequence. 1.60 \@writefi

Tags: errors, texshop

Im having this weird error that says:

```
Underfined Control Sequence. 1.60 \@writefi
```

I can press [s] on the command line and the message is ignored, and the code still runs ...

What can be causing this error?

Comment: You stopped compilation and a write was not completed. Clear auxiliaries.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides But I didn't force compilation to stop. Why would this happen ?

Comment: @NLed the aux file should have the command `\@writefile` but it has become corrupt so you need to delete it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you add that as an answer so that I can mark it as correct ?

Comment: additional useful commentary is present in answers to the (closed) question [Debugging LaTeX Errors: how to isolate the problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191190/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton you *do* realise that I asked that question more than a year ago, right ?

Comment: @Razor -- yes, i know it's an old question, but the question i linked has been closed with this one cited as a duplicate.  since this question is now the "canonical" one, i thought it better to give a link rather than adding another answer that isn't my own.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Fair enough.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Interestingly enough, I'm having a very similar problem, with the exact same error message (down to the line number, `! Undefined control sequence. l.60 \@writef`, but I can open the aux file, and its got a complete line: `\@writefile{snm}{\beamer@slide {stuff}{19}}`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor -- i think you have hit on something useful here.  this sounds like (as david says) an .aux file has become corrupt, most likely because a buffer was not completely written out when something failed and ended the run.  if this is reproducible for you, you can probably go onto chat and find someone who isn't afraid of using the tex debugging tools (often nasty stuff) and is capable of interpreting their results in a finite amount of time, and ask for help.  the fact that `beamer` is cited in the message sounds like a useful direction.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I spent a while last night trying to reproduce in a minimal example, but wasn't able to quite get it.  It seems to require `\include`d files, and doing some `\mode...` switching in beamer's article mode.  In the meantime, I've just got to press through and finish and present the slides, but in a few days I should be able to take a deeper look.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `aux` file should have the command `\@writefile` but it has become corrupt so you need to delete it.

Comment: Wow thanks this really saved me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the deletion of `aux` file did not help.

After some time, I found out that it was caused by full memory - after freeing about 2 GB, the compilation succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional answer, as deleting `.aux` files and restarting to clear ram did not help as other answers suggested:

My problem was that some of the images I use in my report are automatically generated by a Python script, and that I halted execution midway causing one of the images to be incorrectly formatted. Re-generating the image and allowing it to save properly, then deleting the `.aux` file and recompiling fixed my issues.