# Debugging LaTeX Errors: how to isolate the problem

Tags: errors

Using TeXWorks and TeXLive, usually errors display the relevant text, and I can go find the problem.  Of course, it would be nice if there were a button I could click to go there, but it's not crippling.  However, I now have a large document, and suddenly, I get the following error, with no clue about where in the document it is failing:

```
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty)
(c:/bin/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty)

(./QuickFlippedLessons2.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.75 \@writefil

?
```

I don't have a previous version saved, so finding this could be an extremely tedious process of deleting sections until I find the relevant one.  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Don't you have (more or less) unlimited `undo` in your editor?

Comment: A previous compilation must have stopped unexpectedly and written something into the auxiliary file. Delete the .aux file and try again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line right before the error message

```
(./QuickFlippedLessons2.aux
```

shows that the error is happening inside an auxiliary file.

`\@writefile` is a LaTeX kernel command, `\@writefil` is a truncated version. Perhaps a previous run was aborted for some reason and the auxiliary file got closed with open write buffers.

Delete `QuickFlippedLessons2.aux` and try again.

Comment: Do you know of anything that could cause the aux file to still appear intact but for this error to come about?  I've having a very similar error about an undefined `\@writef`, but I can open the .aux file and see a complete line.  I can ask a new question, of course, but since you mentioned "the auxiliary file got closed with open write buffers", I wonder if some elaboration on that might clear anything up.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor There is a contradiction: The file cannot stop at `\@writef` and show the full line at the same time. Either there are different `.aux` files or different times.

Comment: Yes, it's quite puzzling.  I'm compiling from within emacs via auctex, getting the error that the aux file ends with `\@writef`, and yet when I open it up, it clearly doesn't end there.  Your mention of open buffers made me wonder if somehow pdflatex was reading the file before everything got flushed out.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor LaTeX reads the `.aux` file in `\begin{document}`, then the file is opened for writing, finally it is closed and read again in `\end{document}`. Therefore you have to figure out, when which `.aux` file is read with `\@writef`. If `\nofiles` is specified, LaTeX won't write the `.aux file. Also try compiling the file on the command line to exclude that emacs/aucTeX is interfering.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this;  I've tracked it down to something with beamer's article modes, and I've managed to get rid of the problem.  It seems to be a case where the error message doesn't really line up with what the problem actually is.  When I get a few moments, I'll try to work up an MWE and post a question about it (along with the solution, though it doesn't really explain the particular error message).  Again, thank you for your attention to this!

Answer (score 6):

The `()` in the console or log file indicate included files.  So this error is happening while LaTeX is processing the `QuickFlippedLessons2.aux` file.  The `l.` at the beginning of the line indicates the line number.  So this is telling you that there is an undefined control sequence `\@writefil` on line 75 of `QuickFlippedLessons2.aux`.

Now `.aux` files are automatically created during a prior LaTeX run, and read at `\begin{document}` of the current run. Unless you are intentionally writing to the `.aux` file, my guess is that you had a prior aborted LaTeX run that only partially wrote something to the `.aux` file.

If that is the case, hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> at this error will command LaTeX to continue compiling as best it can.  If this is the only problem, the run will succeed and the `.aux` file will be correctly written, and the error will go away in future runs.

Alternatively, you can delete the `.aux` file and recompile.  The first run will write the `.aux` file correctly.

(Heiko beat me by a minute, but I'll keep the post since I tried to go into more detail.)

Comment: thanks!  gave priority to the first answer but upchecked both.  Hopefully this will solve it.